# How can I remove the italics in the article title in my references? I am using natbib with apalike2

Tags: cross-referencing, natbib

I need to format my references for the International Review of Economics and Finance. Which means that they should look pretty much like the output I get combining natbib with apalike, with the difference that they should not have the name of the journal in italics.
How can I change this?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5001) Does the journal provide a bibtex style file?

Answer (score 1):

Excerpting from the journal's own [guidelines for authors](http://www.elsevier.com/journals/international-review-of-economics-and-finance/1059-0560/guide-for-authors#20300):

> **References**
>
> There are no strict requirements on reference formatting at submission. References can be in any style or format as long as the style is consistent. Where applicable, author(s) name(s), journal title/book title, chapter title/article title, year of publication, volume number/book chapter and the pagination must be present. Use of DOI is highly encouraged. The reference style used by the journal will be applied to the accepted article by Elsevier at the proof stage.

Given the journal is in the "Elsevier family" of journals, you may want to give `elsarticle-harv` a try. However, I wouldn't spend too much time at this point selecting the "perfect" bibliography style.